# Simple for loop in composite component

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, composite-component

I want to create a simple for loop in a composite component.
I have a component that is supposed to display a character *n* times. This seems to be like the simplest scenario. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:composite="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
                xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <composite:interface>
        <composite:attribute name="length" required="true" shortDescription="The length of the anonymized text"/>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
            <c:forEach begin="0" end="#{cc.attrs.length}">•</c:forEach>
    </composite:implementation>
</ui:composition>
```

This errors out:

`javax.faces.FacesException: Error Instantiating: com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.ImplementationHandler`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this by creating an an util class in java that creates an empty array to iterate over with `<ui:repeat />`

**view:**

```
<ui:repeat value="#{util:createArray(cc.attrs.length)}" var="index">•</ui:repeat>
```

**util class:**

```
public final class UIHelper {
    public static Object[] createArray(int size) {
        return new Object[size];
    }
}
```

**taglib:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <facelet-taglib
...
<function>
    <function-name>createArray</function-name>
    <function-class>package.UIHelper</function-class>
    <function-signature>Object[] createArray(int)</function-signature>
</function> </facelet-taglib>
```